# how to switchback to user with uid 1000 in shellscript

Tags: command-line, scripts

I Have created the following shell script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
...


    #Cleanup 
    sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
    sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults

    ln -s /etc/drupal/7  /home/$USER/drupal 

exit
```

Now I'd like to create the symbolic link for the user with uid 1000 but not for the root user.

What code whould help?

Thank you for any ideas

Josh

Answer (score 2):

You can use getent to resolve the user name for 1000.

```
user=$(getent passwd 1000 | awk -F: '{ print $1 }')
```

Then check if directory exists.

```
if test -d "/home/$user"; then
     ln -s /etc/drupal/7  "/home/$user/drupal" 
fi
```

note:

you can go one farther, and use

```
dir=$(getent passwd 1000 | awk -F: '{ print $6 }')
```

to get the correct home dir for the user.